# Quais são diferenças de download binário, auto LF, auto std e text?

Tags: ftp, download, sftp

No bitvise ssh, tem as opções de modo de upload e download que são **binary**, **auto LF**, **auto std** e **text**. Quais são as diferenças entre elas ?